# Switching fragments using onClickListener

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin

I have a "home page" in my app that looks like the following

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_home.*

class HomeActivity: Fragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false)

        return  view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        ButtonAddition.setOnClickListener{

        }
    }



}
```

I have a mainActivity that has the following code in it

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.MenuItem
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.app_bar_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)


        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close
        )
        drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
        displayScreen(-1)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    private fun displayScreen(id: Int) {
        val fragment: Fragment = when (id) {

            R.id.home -> {
                HomeActivity()
            }
            R.id.record -> {
                HomeActivity()
            }
            R.id.pro -> {
                HomeActivity()
            }
            R.id.about -> {
                HomeActivity()
            }
            else -> {
                HomeActivity()
            }
        }

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.relativelayout, fragment)
            .commit()

    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        displayScreen(item.itemId)
        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }

}
```

I also have a "AdditionSplash" fragment i am trying to switch to with the following code in it

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup

class AdditionSplash: Fragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_addition_splash, container, false)

        return view
    }
}
```

on the homepage fragment I have an onclicklistener and I want to use that to switch to the `additionsplash` fragment from the homepage fragment. ( don't want to use that navigation drawer I have for that) I can get this to work if i change the additionsplash fragment into an activity and use intents, but i can't seem to switch to a fragment from a fragment.
Is this impossible to do? I want to use that button to just swap to a different fragment.

here is the solution i came up with thanks to a suggestion

In the main activity I did:

```
fun chooseActivity(view: View){
        val buttonClicked = view as Button
        val fragment: Fragment = when (buttonClicked.id) {

            R.id.ButtonAddition -> {
                AdditionSplash()
            }

            else -> {
                HomeActivity()
            }
        }
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.relativelayout, fragment)
            .commit()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call it from host activity of your fragment, like you did it in your 
MainActivity:

```
activity?.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.relativelayout, fragment)
            .commit()
```